# how do you re-type a "generic" typed object

Tags: typescript

I have a service that makes api calls to various endpoints, and so I have an extremely very generic type defined for the responses:

```
export interface ApiResponseItem {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | ApiResponseItem | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

export interface Item {
  attributes?: ApiResponseItem,
  ...etc
}
```

so an api call may come back with a response like:

```
{
  things: [ { id: 123, actions: [ { name: foo }, { name: bar } ],
}
```

So later on, when I have a class that actually wants to render specific things that is knows about-- I want to be able to have the object be properly typed:

```
interface Action {
  name: string
}

export class SomeClass {
  actions: Action[];

  constructor (item: Item) {
    this.actions = item.attributes.actions;
  }
}
```

```
 error TS2322: Type '(string | number | boolean)[]' is not assignable to type 'Action[]'.
  Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
```

The only way I could get this to work was to do:

```
this.actions = item.attributes.actions as unknown as action[]
```

How can I do this without having to double cast with `unknown` and `action[]`

Comment: In statically typed languages the term "generic" has a *specific* technical meaning, and you have no generics. I see the scare quotes, but you may want to edit the title and body of this. The solution to this would be to use *actual* generics to allow the caller to specify the response schema on each call.

Comment: Is this an Angular question? If so you might want to tag it as such; if not, could you remove the example's dependency on things like `OnInit` and terms like "component"?

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs since `this.item.attributes.actions` can have many types like string, boolean etc. However, `this.actions` accepts only values of type Action[] which is of a structure `{ name: string }[]`.
From my point of view and as far as I see from your question, you have to rethink your structure how you extract and assign data from the API to your component.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer and is better suited as [a comment once you have sufficient reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: and that makes zero sense to me--  if `this.item.attributes.actions` can have many types such as an object with a string key, and a value of a string and it has been assigned the value of this object: `{ 'name': 'hello world' }`,  Then why in the world does Typescript not let me assign that object to a type of `{  name: string }` when that is exactly what it contains?  This is one of many reasons why I find Typescript to be obnoxious and dumb.